# Set text_field width, style works but class doesn't

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to vary the size of some input fields. I can get it to work with an inline style but trying to use twitter bootstrap or just a class does not work.

My form has

```
<tr>
    <div class="field">
      <td><%= f.label :item %></td>
      <td><%= f.text_field :item,  style: "width: 150px" %></td>
    </div>
  </tr>


  <tr class="field_100">
    <div class="field">
      <td ><%= f.label :number_of_rolls_fill %></td>
      <td><%= f.number_field :number_of_rolls_fill, class: "field_100" %></td>
    </div>
  </tr>
```

What I see is

[image]

In other words, the inline style works but not the class.

I have a class set up in application.css

```
field_100 {
    width: 100px !important;
    background-color: #2AADD5 !important ;
}
```

If I do a view source on the page, I see

```
<tr>
    <div class="field">
      <td><label for="bedsheet_line_item">Item</label></td>
      <td><input style="width: 150px" type="text" value="1" name="bedsheet_line[item]" id="bedsheet_line_item" /></td>
    </div>
  </tr>

  <tr class="field_100">
    <div class="field">
      <td ><label for="bedsheet_line_number_of_rolls_fill">Number of rolls fill</label></td>
      <td><input class="field_100" type="number" value="1" name="bedsheet_line[number_of_rolls_fill]" id="bedsheet_line_number_of_rolls_fill" /></td>
    </div>
  </tr>
```

If I inspect the second field where I am trying to use the class, it points to around line 1122 of my style.css main template. That is the second block below

```
  input[type="text"], input[type="password"], input[type="email"], input[type="url"], input[type="color"], input[type="date"], input[type="datetime"], input[type="datetime-local"], input[type="month"], input[type="number"], input[type="range"], input[type="tel"], input[type="time"], input[type="week"], textarea
        {
           background: #FFFFFF;
           -webkit-border-radius:4px;
           -moz-border-radius:4px;
           border-radius:4px;
           border:1px solid #B9B59D;
           margin:0 auto;
        }
        input[type="text"], input[type="password"], input[type="email"], input[type="url"], input[type="color"], input[type="date"], input[type="datetime"], input[type="datetime-local"], input[type="month"], input[type="number"], input[type="range"], input[type="tel"], input[type="time"], input[type="week"], textarea
        {
           width: 100%;
           padding: 4px 0;
           color: #302E22 !important;
           font-size: 13px;
           font-family: Arial, 'Arial Unicode MS', Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
           font-weight: normal;
           font-style: normal;
           text-shadow: none;
```

These are internal low use apps so I could live with inline styles if necessary. However, I would like to get this working with classes. My plan is to have different classes such as field_150, field_200, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you forgot the dot in front of the class name in your code:

```
field_100 {
    width: 100px !important;
    background-color: #2AADD5 !important ;
}
```

your style would only by applied to a <field_100> - Tag.

Use the dot to select by class name:

```
.field_100 {
    width: 100px !important;
    background-color: #2AADD5 !important ;
}
```

Comment: That did the trick. I thought I had tried that but apparently not.